# Creating a new Table Entry with an ID from another table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to attach user_id (so I can access user details) to comments that are already attached to a page called Park.

I have three tables set up up: Park, Comment, and User:

```
class Park < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :comments
    has_many :users

end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :park
    has_one :user

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   has_many :comments

   validates_presence_of :username
    validates :username, uniqueness: true

  def admin?
    admin
  end
end
```

As you can see above, I'm using the Devise gem for users and authorizations.

Comments show on Park and so they are nested:

```
park_comment GET    /parks/:park_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
```

My comment controller is set up like this:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create]
    before_action :authorize_admin!, only: [:delete]

    def create
        @park = Park.find(params[:park_id])
        @comment = @park.comments.create(comment_params)
        redirect_to park_path(@park)

    end

    def destroy
        @park = Park.find(params[:park_id])
        @comment = @park.comments.find(params[:id])
        @comment.destroy

        redirect_to park_path(@park)
    end

    private
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:comment, :user_id, :park_id)
    end
end
```

I've been able to oscillate from park_id to user_id, but the trade off has consistently been to receive a big fat nil on the other term.

I just tried to add a hidden field to my comment form

```
<%= form_for([@park, @park.comments.build]) do |f| %>
<p>
<%= f.label :comment %><br>
<%= f.text_area :comment %>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:user_id, current_user.id) %>
</p>
<p>
        <%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

But that didn't seem to yield any results.

I had tried some ActiveRecord joining work, but it didn't want to latch on to my create so I gave that up. Having spent a while on this now, I'm convinced there's an easy solution I'm just not seeing. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `hidden_field_tag` isn't working. It'll create a separate param, not one nested under the param key that you want.

My suggestion would be to remove the hidden_field altogether and specify the current_user in the controller.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @park = Park.find(params[:park_id])
    @comment =  @park.
                comments.
                create(
                  comment_params.
                  merge(user_id: current_user.id) # adding here, on creation
                  # or merge(user: current_user)
                )
    redirect_to park_path(@park)
  end

  def comment_params
    params.
    require(:comment).
    permit(:comment)
  end

end
```

Why? Because otherwise a user can potentially change the value of that hidden_field and you'll be incorrectly storing the comment's user_id value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but looking at your code I can see some problems.

first of all, you create a hidden field but not using the form helper. That's why your user_id is not visible in your `comment_params`, causing your

> big fat nil

:) .
Try to change

```
<%= hidden_field_tag(:user_id, current_user.id) %>
```

to

```
<%= f.hidden_field(:user_id, :value => current_user.id) %>
```

But a better Idea for this is to just remove the hidden field and change your controller to

```
  def create
    @park = Park.find(params[:park_id])
    @comment = @park.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to park_path(@park)
    else
      ...
    end
  end
```

You can now remove your `:user_id` from your `comment_params` like this:

```
params.require(:comment).permit(:comment, :park_id)
```

Actually, you don't even need `:park_id` in there